# Windows Explorer view style via GPO or registry edit

Tags: windows

I'm having some difficulty adjusting the default view style in windows explorer (e.g. list, detail, large icon, small icon). There does not seem to be any pre-baked GPOs for this and next to no documentation on the subject outside of using GUI configuration tools built into windows explorer.

Does anyone know the specific registry keys that need to be edited for this?
I've already taken a look at HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Settings but the adjustments I've made there don't seem to make any change on their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no supported mechanism to make the change you're looking for. That's why you're not finding any docs about it.

This setting is stored in an undocumented binary blob that isn't easily amenable to modification with Group Policy Administrative Templates.